# How to configure the runtime constraints on resources in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I want to tune some constrains on resources which are exposed by Docker
http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources

But I don't how to do that in Kubernetes.
Does Kubernetes expose all these configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubernetes can limit memory and cpu only for now: read [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/user-guide/compute-resources.md#container-and-pod-resource-limits)

They do have plans to support more resources: [Future resource types](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/design/resources.md)